# React JS: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I'm trying to parse and get fetch data from URL, but got the error like:

> `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

the URL contains this such of data:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:kict="kict" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://192.168.0.70:28080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd kict http://192.168.0.70:28080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=kict%3Av_plans_photo">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
</gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
<kict:v_plans_photo fid="v_plans_photo.fid-400b9b06_17e425c6260_-1a99">
<kict:rownum>61689</kict:rownum>
<kict:plan_id>6178a7a0974e58001ac90ac5</kict:plan_id>
<kict:cmo>5c38212c23b65b0d045d2de8</kict:cmo>
<kict:cmo_str>5c38212c23b65b0d045d2de8</kict:cmo_str>
<kict:plan_name/>
<kict:plan_cn>포트홀 작업추가</kict:plan_cn>
<kict:opert_ty>B1</kict:opert_ty>
<kict:operTy>B1</kict:operTy>
<kict:opert_sttus>A4</kict:opert_sttus>
<kict:opert_plan_cn>포트홀 작업추가</kict:opert_plan_cn>
<kict:create_at_year>2021</kict:create_at_year>
<kict:create_at_month>10</kict:create_at_month>
<kict:create_at_week>43.0</kict:create_at_week>
<kict:created_at>2021-10-27T01:13:04.557Z</kict:created_at>
<kict:created_by>강릉_보수원002</kict:created_by>
<kict:cvpl_ty>5cfda3bab615b60845c79dda</kict:cvpl_ty>
<kict:acmslts_id>6178a89e974e58001ac90b02</kict:acmslts_id>
<kict:cvpl_ty_code>900900</kict:cvpl_ty_code>
<kict:cvpl_ty_nm>포트홀</kict:cvpl_ty_nm>
<kict:cvpl_name>포트홀</kict:cvpl_name>
<kict:cmo_org_code>1613208</kict:cmo_org_code>
<kict:cmo_grp_nm>원주청</kict:cmo_grp_nm>
<kict:cmo_code>22</kict:cmo_code>
<kict:cmo_nm>강릉국토관리사무소</kict:cmo_nm>
<kict:cmoNm>강릉국토관리사무소</kict:cmoNm>
<kict:photo_type>완료</kict:photo_type>
<kict:begin_lat>37.7164584026444</kict:begin_lat>
<kict:begin_lon>128.987696737366</kict:begin_lon>
<kict:photo_lat>37.7161098</kict:photo_lat>
<kict:photo_lon>128.9880585</kict:photo_lon>
<kict:geom>
<gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">128.9880585,37.7161098</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Point>
</kict:geom>
<kict:photo_url>http://hms.molit.go.kr:9080/api/uploads/2021/6178a7a0974e58001ac90ac5_202110271017147661635297434478.png</kict:photo_url>
<kict:store_path>uploads/2021/6178a7a0974e58001ac90ac5_202110271017147661635297434478.png</kict:store_path>
<kict:photo_filename>6178a7a0974e58001ac90ac5_202110271017147661635297434478.png</kict:photo_filename>
<kict:photo_size>1122621</kict:photo_size>
</kict:v_plans_photo>
</gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

I just used `fetch` to parse and fetch data like below:

```
let url = "/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=kict:v_plans_photo&srsName=EPSG:4326&maxFeatures=10000&format_options=callback:getJson&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(geom, POINT (128.9880585 37.7161098))"

if (url) {
    fetch(url, {
       headers : { 
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
     },
     (error) => {
      this.setState({
         isLoaded: true,
         error
       });
       console.log(`fetch failed: ${this.state.error}`)
       }
     )
  }
```

How can I get data from that URL using `fetch`?

Comment: can you check applying `JSON. parse()` to the response ?

Comment: @ShoyebMemon I've tried but it said: `VM1323:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: You need to convert the response to Json format first. Directly calling response.json() throws you the above error mentioned in your question. Go through this answer, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393985/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-reactjs

Comment: WTH are you trying to parse XML as JSON? That can't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is throwing such error because you are trying to parse a non-json datatype.
Response data is actually an XML. You have to first parse the text and then parse the XML.

Refer this - https://codetogo.io/how-to-fetch-xml-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

[Visit this page for detailed info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json)

> The json() method of the Response interface takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise which resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.

> Note that despite the method being named json(), the result is not JSON but is instead the result of taking JSON as input and parsing it to produce a JavaScript object.

As you can see, the json() takes JSON format as input and then parses it, as your data is not in a JSON format you are bound to get the following error

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Your result is in XML format. Try the following

```
let url = "/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=kict:v_plans_photo&srsName=EPSG:4326&maxFeatures=10000&format_options=callback:getJson&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(geom, POINT (128.9880585 37.7161098))"

if (url) {
    fetch(url, {
       headers : { 
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(response => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const xml = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
      console.log(xml);
    },
     (error) => {
      this.setState({
         isLoaded: true,
         error
       });
       console.log(`fetch failed: ${this.state.error}`)
       }
     )
  }
```